# Webpack: TypeError: Cannot read property 'properties' of undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack

Here is the branch and repo in question: https://github.com/Futuratum/moon.holdings/tree/dev

> /Users/leongaban/projects/Futuratum/moon.holdings/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/config-yargs.js:89
>                                   describe: optionsSchema.definitions.output.properties.path.description,

Not sure why I'm getting this error, but I upgraded from Webpack 3 to 4.

**webpack**

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';
import CopyWebpackPlugin from 'copy-webpack-plugin';
import path from 'path';

const moonholdings = path.resolve(__dirname, 'moonholdings');
const app = path.resolve(__dirname, 'app');
const nodeModules = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules');

const HtmlWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: path.join(__dirname, '/app/index.html'),
  inject: 'body'
});

const ExtractTextPluginConfig = new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: 'moonholdings.css',
  disable: false,
  allChunks: true
});

const CopyWebpackPluginConfigOptions = [{
  from: 'app/static',
  to: 'static/'
}];

const CopyWebpackPluginConfig = new CopyWebpackPlugin(CopyWebpackPluginConfigOptions);

const PATHS = {
  app,
  build: moonholdings
};

const LAUNCH_COMMAND = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;

const isProduction = LAUNCH_COMMAND === 'production';
process.env.BABEL_ENV = LAUNCH_COMMAND;

const productionPlugin = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env': {
    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
  }
});

const base = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', PATHS.app],
  performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxAssetSize: 1000000
  },
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [app, nodeModules]
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)/,
        loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'
      }
    ]
  }
};

const developmentConfig = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  devServer: {
    contentBase: moonholdings
  },
  plugins: [
    CopyWebpackPluginConfig,
    ExtractTextPluginConfig,
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig
  ]
};

const productionConfig = {
  devtool: false,
  plugins: [
    CopyWebpackPluginConfig,
    ExtractTextPluginConfig,
    HtmlWebpackPluginConfig,
    productionPlugin
  ]
};

export default Object.assign(
  {}, base,
  isProduction === true ? productionConfig : developmentConfig
);
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "moon.holdings",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Cryptocurrency asset portfolio",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": "https://github.com/Futuratum/moon.holdings.git",
  "author": "Leon Gaban <leongaban@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack && webpack-dev-server",
    "webpack": "webpack-dev-server",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack -p",
    "production": "webpack -p",
    "test": "yarn run test-eslint; yarn run test-jest:update",
    "test-eslint": "eslint app",
    "test-eslint:fix": "eslint --fix app",
    "test-sasslint": "./node_modules/.bin/sass-lint 'app/**/*.scss' -v -q",
    "test-jest": "jest",
    "test-jest:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test-jest:coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "test-jest:update": "jest --updateSnapshot"
  },
  "setupFiles": [
    "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js",
    "<rootDir>/src/setupTests.js"
  ],
  "now": {
    "name": "moonholdings",
    "alias": "moon.holdings"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {},
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "app"
    ],
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "./app/utils/testConfigure.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.10",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint": "^4.18.2",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-node": "^0.3.2",
    "eslint-plugin-dependencies": "^2.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "flexboxgrid": "^6.3.1",
    "git-hooks": "^1.1.10",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.6",
    "jest": "^22.4.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "path-to-regexp": "^2.2.0",
    "ramda": "^0.25.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^0.6.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "rest": "^2.0.0",
    "sass-lint": "^1.12.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.2",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "svg-loader": "^0.0.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.20.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: it works fine for me, can you clarify which script gives the error? What node and npm version do you use? In general what are steps before reproducing the error? I tried both dev and build. Work perfectly fine.

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan node: `v10.8.0` npm `6.4.1` and wait you downloaded the repo and it built and run fine? Which branch?

Comment: Exactly, branch is dev. I am 98 % sure it's the node. Try to install latest LTS version of node v8.12.0 and check again

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan something was wrong with my local repo. I trashed it and re-pulled master and it's running again. I also did switch to Node 8.11 using NVM. Like to post your answer? I think just something got jacked up in my local repo.

Comment: I added the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to install latest LTS version of Node and test again. Works perfectly fine for me with latest LTS node and npm.

Answer (score 43):

If it is happening after you have updated npm packages , then remove and reinstall webpack webpack-cli
`npm remove webpack webpack-cli`
`npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli`

 I would suggest you to upgrade/update node before doing anything.

Answer (score 12):

There are two things you need to do:

1. Remove webpack@4.20.2 and webpack-cli@2.0.10 dependency and specifically install webpack@4.19.0 and webpack-cli@3.0.4 version. Webpack [4.20.x release has error](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8082).
2. Also do not use `extract-text-webpack-plugin`.

`extract-text-webpack-plugin` should not be used with Webpack 4 to extract CSS. It doesn't work. Instead of this, try using: [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin).

After these changes, webpack should compile your code and generate necessary bundle.

*Note: When I cloned mentioned repository on my system, I had to make changes to `board.js` file. I made change to this import statement: `import CoinMarketCap from 'components/Partials/Coinmarketcap/link';` This doesn't work on Linux system as paths are case sensitive.*

Comment: it does work, it's not advised. But it totally works. In our project we use latest webpack build with extract-text plugin with 0 issues

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan, extract-text-webpack-plugin will not work will Webpack 4. Use of `allChunks` property inside extract plugin causes entire build to break and not just warnings.

Comment: Then there is something specific to your build. I am telling you we never had any problems with or without allChunks: true. I just double checked it's still working. Check your build, try extract-text-webpack-plugin@next version

Comment: I completed step 1, however `yarn install` produces this error: `error upath@1.0.4: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=4 <=9".` And breaks, stopping the package installs.

Comment: Did not solve it for me. Am using Webpack `4.3.0` and had tried reverting to `4.19.0`

Comment: @vsync Can you elaborate on the problem in more details?

Comment: I found out I wasn't supposed to use `extract-text-webpack-plugin` with Webpack `v4` but use `mini-css-extract-plugin`, but regardless still am having the problem, when I define the `output` property in the config file

Answer (score 11):

It's **^** symbol in "webpack-cli": "^2.0.10" dependency which resulting to minor/patch version getting upgraded to latest webpack-cli@2.x.x, which has following change.

Change in webpack resulting in the issue: (change output to outputOptions)
REF: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/pull/605

Solution: (installing webpack-cli@3.x.x)

npm uninstall webpack-cli

npm install --save-dev webpack-cli@3.1.1

REF:[Solution](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/607)

Comment: Running on MacOS Catalina 10.15.5, process worked for me:
npm uninstall webpack 
npm uninstall webpack-cli
npm uninstall webpack-dev-server
npm install webpack
npm install webpack-cli
npm install webpack-dev-server

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I just forgot to return the `middlewares` array in the `setupMiddlewares` function, like this:

```
devServer: {
    setupMiddlewares: (middlewares, devServer) => {
        // Smth very important

        return middlewares
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had done the same thing! ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

migrating to latest version solved the error for me: webpack-cli^3.3.11

Comment: Upgrading it to 3.3.12 throws "TypeError: Cannot read property 'tapAsync' of undefined" error