# TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of null when deploying to Vercel

Tags: webpack, error-handling, deployment, vercel

Just leaving this here in case anybody else bumps into the same issue - when deploying with Vercel I get a TypeError when it's Creating an optimized production build...

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hash' of null
 at callback (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/webpack/bundle5.js:59190:46)
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a fix, the thing that worked, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54152321/12777068) is reinstalling webpack:

```
npm remove webpack webpack-cli

npm install --save-dev webpack webpack-cli
```